# While with PHP Simple Templates

Tags: php, template-engine

I used php template of overthemike ([php-templates](https://github.com/overthemike/php-templates)), but it does not work with function while (on mysql)...

Display the correct category:

```
1.PC
    1.Power
    2.VGA
    3.RAM
    4.Audio
2.Laptop
    1.Monitor
    2.Pin
    3.Keyboard
```

After running:

```
1.PC
    3.Power
    4.VGA
    5.RAM
    6.Audio
    7.Monitor
    8.Pin
    9.Keyboard
2.Laptop
    3.Power
    4.VGA
    5.RAM
    6.Audio
    7.Monitor
    8.Pin
    9.Keyboard
```

Example: http://www.mediafire.com/?fln71mh5pwqjn7m

Why does a code fill all the space available to it?

Can you help me fix this code?

Comment: I don't think anyone is going to download that file you linked to.  Who knows what's in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data = array();

while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM category WHERE sub = ".$result["id"]." ORDER BY id ASC");

    while($resub = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        $data[$result["title"]][] = array(
            "id"=>$resub["id"],
            "title"=>$resub["title"],
        );

    }

}
print_r($data);
```

This should work. Also I think that you should use something else because this is not good solution for what you want to achieve.